# Como fazer um join de 2 tabelas e onde 2 campos da tabela A se referem ao mesmo campo da tabela B?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o comando *SQL* que não funciona:

```
SELECT
    GAT_requisicao.id_GATrequisicao as 'ID Requisição',
    GAP_atendimento.id_GAPatendimento as 'ID Atendimento',
    GR_paciente.nome_GRpaciente as 'Nome Paciente',
    GR_setor.nome_GRsetor as 'Setor Requisitante',
    GR_setor.nome_GRsetor as 'Setor Executante'
FROM
    GAT_requisicao, GAP_atendimento, GR_paciente, GR_setor
WHERE
    GAT_requisicao.GAPatendimento_id = GAP_atendimento.id_GAPatendimento
AND GAP_atendimento.paciente_GAPatendimento = GR_paciente.nrcarteira_GRpaciente
AND GAT_requisicao.setorReq_GATrequisicao = GR_setor.id_GRsetor
AND GAT_requisicao.setorExec_GATrequisicao = GR_setor.id_GRsetor;
```

Na tabela `GAT_requisicao` eu tenho 2 colunas:

- setorReq_GATrequisicao
- setorExec_GATrequisicao

Uma fica salvo o setor requisitante e na outra o setor executante e essas colunas são preenchidas com `FK` da tabela `GR_setor`, porém o que acontece:

Se eu pedir no `select` para ver o `setorReq` e o `setorExec` e ligar as 2 tabelas, não me retorna nada, só consigo fazer 1 ligação por vez, ou ligar `setorExec` a tabela `GR_setor` ou ligar `setorReq` a tabela `GR_setor`, as 2 ligações ao mesmo retorno o retorno vem nulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer fazer o `join` para a mesma tabela a partir de diferentes fks, então pode usar o `inner join`  no lugar do `where`, e ligar corretamente as chaves, assim:

```
SELECT
    GAT_requisicao.id_GATrequisicao as 'ID Requisição',
    GAP_atendimento.id_GAPatendimento as 'ID Atendimento',
    GR_paciente.nome_GRpaciente as 'Nome Paciente',
    GR_setor.nome_GRsetor as 'Setor Requisitante',
    GR_setor.nome_GRsetor as 'Setor Executante'
FROM
    GAT_requisicao
INNER JOIN GAP_atendimento ON GAT_requisicao.GAPatendimento_id = GAP_atendimento.id_GAPatendimento
INNER JOIN GR_paciente ON GAP_atendimento.paciente_GAPatendimento = GR_paciente.nrcarteira_GRpaciente
INNER JOIN GR_setor AS GR_setor_req ON GAT_requisicao.setorReq_GATrequisicao = GR_setor_req.id_GRsetor
INNER JOIN GR_setor AS GR_setor_exec ON GAT_requisicao.setorExec_GATrequisicao = GR_setor_exec.id_GRsetor;
```

Comment: Não é necessario colocar no from as tabelas que estão sendo usadas no comando? 
Tipo: 
FROM
    GAT_requisicao, GAP_atendimento, GR_paciente, GR_setor

Comment: Sim, estão na cláusula `from`, porém com o `inner join` na frente.

Comment: Entendi. Eu testei esse comando que você sugeriu e não funcionou, o MySQL Workbench retorna esse erro: "Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'GR_setor.nome_GRsetor' in 'field list'". Apesar de que dentro da tabela GR_setor existe sim a coluna nome_GRsetor.

Comment: coloca `GR_setor_req.nome_GRsetor` e `GR_setor_exec.nome_GRsetor`

Comment: Obrigado @RovannLinhalis e Ricardo Pontual, após essa alteração funcionou.